# Disable GPUScaling with Nividia binary driver 304

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, proprietary

In former drivers there was an option in the nvidia-settings GUI for that.
I also tried it manually:

```
nvidia-settings --assign=GPUScaling=131074
```

Which gives me:

```
ERROR: The attribute 'GPUScaling' specified in assignment 'GPUScaling=131074' cannot
       be assigned (it is a read-only attribute).
```

I also do not know if `131074` is a correct value. Other values give the same error.
Do I have to revert to an older driver or is there a hack that can prevent my GT8800 from doing GPU scaling.

Answer (score 0):

There are still options described in the [documentation for xorg.conf](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/304.64/README/xconfigoptions.html).

> ```
> Option "FlatPanelProperties" "string"
> ```
>
> This option requests particular properties for all or a subset of the
>   connected flat panels.
>
> [...]
>
> Recognized properties:
>
> - "Scaling": controls the flat panel scaling mode; possible values are:
>
>   - 'Default' (the driver will use whichever scaling state is current),
>   - 'Native' (the driver will use the flat panel's scaler, if possible),
>   - 'Scaled' (the driver will use the NVIDIA GPU's scaler, if possible),
>   - 'Centered' (the driver will center the image, if possible),
>   - and 'aspect-scaled' (the X driver will scale with the NVIDIA GPU's scaler,
>       but keep the aspect ratio correct).

So you either use `Native` and have the image scaled by the flat panel or `Centered` and have no scaling applied at all.

Comment: can you give me some details how i can set this up. I do not have an `xorg.conf`. Do I set this option in the `.nvidia-settings-rc`?

Comment: You can generate a `xorg.conf` file with `nvidia-settings`. Option lines like these are usually added to the device section. There a also examples on how to configure multiple monitors.

Comment: But doesn't that contradict to the `xorg.conf`-free configuration model that Ubuntu adopted since several releases? You say there is now way around that? I still remember the many hours spent tweaking my xorg.conf (multi monitor) in 2006 ;). I do not want to go back, I'd rather use the old driver.

Comment: You just configure the necessary parts that you specifically want to configure yourself, everything else is still automatically configured.